# Bold math inside of absolute value gives error

Tags: math-mode, bold

This code

```
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:test}
  | \mathbf{v} |
\end{equation}
```

gives me the error:

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: \mathbf allowed only in math mode.

--- TeX said ---

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.430   | \mathbf
                 {v} |
```

My question is simply why? Is not **equation** math mode??

Comment: Please provide a Complete working example that shows the problem. Most likely you have loaded a package that redefines `|` to do something, but we can't help just given that fragment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post a complete MWE (minimum working example) that produces the error you're encountering. (The above code, preceded by `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` and succeeded by `\end{document}`, does *not* generate an error.) It may be that the error is caused by a missing math delimiter somewhere prior to the equation you're showing.

Comment: It works for me. Did you try your code in a MWE file without additional packages or definitions?

Comment: Hi abbec, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I edited your question to indent the `log` message too. Your snippet works fine for me- could you post a few more details about your distribution? Welcome to the group :)

Comment: I actually found the problem... It was the package program that redefined the `|` to something as you said @David Carlisle. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 8):

You already know that many packages redefine `|`.  Thus I usually recommend using `amsmath` and its commands `\lvert` and `\rvert` for left and right pipe delimiters.  Besides protection against redefinition of `|`, this also makes better spacing when `|` is indeed a delimiter.